# Heroku says "Process exited with status 0" during start of java REST API app

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, web-applications, jax-rs

I want to run my java web app - simple REST API based on JAX-RS at Heroku. Every time build was processed successfully but after hiting correct URL app does not return expected result.

I call URL - https://mandayscz.herokuapp.com/api/month/?month=6&year=2019&hours=8 - this structure worked at localhost. Of course root is different before first slash at localhost.

On the other hand - at localhost it works fine. So it must be something wrong in code or in Heroku env.

GIT of that service is here - https://github.com/pavelpetrcz/MandaysFigu

In Heroku CLI I got log with Status 0. But I could not find what does it mean in my case.

Log from CLI:

```
2019-09-09T21:54:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pavelpetr.cz@gmail.com
2019-09-09T21:54:43.156953+00:00 app[api]: Release v28 created by user pavelpetr.cz@gmail.com
2019-09-09T21:54:43.156953+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1de65d1e by user pavelpetr.cz@gmail.com
2019-09-09T21:54:44.396594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-09-09T21:54:48.438387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main`
2019-09-09T21:54:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-09-09T21:54:50.249092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-09T21:54:50.133290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-09-09T21:54:49.994313+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-09-09T21:54:49.997583+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2019-09-09T21:58:29.232849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/month/?month=6&year=2019&hours=8" host=mandayscz.herokuapp.com request_id=3d65ffb9-65ca-4e00-bdab-c5ed8459d2a0 fwd="89.102.10.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I use java 8, Tomcat, Jersey as implementation for JAX-RS and few more dependencies.

I tried to play around with Procfile. Unsuccessfully.

I want to start my app and be able to get data from database underneath.
Anybody with idea what could I do to start my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application create war file, so you need to adjust Procfile and add `webapp-runner` as dependency to `pom.xml`

**Procfile:**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

More info is in the [Heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner)